# Spark-shell is not working

Tags: apache-spark

When I submit the `spark-shell` command, I see the following error:

```
# spark-shell

> SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
  File "/usr/bin/hdp-select", line 249
    print "Packages:"
                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(t "Packages:")?
ls: cannot access /usr/hdp//hadoop/lib: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: hdp.version is not set while running Spark under HDP, please set through HDP_VERSION in spark-env.sh or add a java-opts file in conf with -Dhdp.version=xxx
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:118)
```

Comment: Can you just add little bit more explanation to your problem ? Is hadoop properly installed on your system ?

Comment: yes, hadoop working fine... I am not sure what can I post more here since I am new to this technology. please let me know, what can I share here... the above details are popup when I issue the 'spark-shell' statement on linux server

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the HDP script /usr/bin/hdp-select is apparently run under Python3, whereas it contains incompatible Python2 specific code.

You may port /usr/bin/hdp-select to Python3 by:

1. adding parentheses to the print statements
2. replacing the line "packages.sort()" by "list(package).sort()")
3. replacing the line "os.mkdir(current, 0755)" by "os.mkdir(current, 0o755)"

You may also try to force HDP to run /usr/bin/hdp-select under Python2:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python2 PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2 spark-shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem: I set `HDP_VERSION` before running spark.

```sh
export HDP_VERSION=<your hadoop version>

spark-shell
```